# Al modificar combobox no trae seleccionado el valor obtenido por GET

Tags: php, html, mysql, combobox

Tengo una tabla con registros de barrios/zonas (ciudades)

tengo el siguiente select donde lleno los option con cada registro de la base mysql.

```
            <select class="form-control" id="barrios" name="barrios" required>
            <option value="">Seleccione:</option>
            <?php
            // Realizos la consulta para extraer los datos
            $query = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT * FROM zona_barrio order by id");
            while ($valores_barrio = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                $id_barrio = $valores_barrio['id'];
                $barrio = $valores_barrio['zona_barrio'];
            // Aqui lleno el select con datos extraidos de la base de datos.
            echo '<option value="'.$barrio.'">'.$barrio.'</option>';
            }
            ?>
            </select>
```

Hasta acá todo ok, el tema se me da cuando desde un datatables agrego un boton para modificar el registro seleccionado por metodo Get llevo el "id" del registro a mi formulario en:

modificar.php

```
<?php
    //DB PARA ABM
    require 'include/conexion.php';
        
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM zona_barrio WHERE id = '$id'";
    $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
    $row = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
?>
        <form method="POST" action="update.php" autocomplete="off">
            <select class="form-control" id="barrios" name="barrios" required>
            <option value="">Seleccione:</option>
            <?php
            // Realizos la consulta para extraer los datos
            $query = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT * FROM zona_barrio order by id");
            while ($valores_barrio = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                $id_barrio = $valores_barrio['id'];
                $barrio = $valores_barrio['zona_barrio'];
            // Aqui lleno el select con datos extraidos de la base de datos.
            echo '<option value="'.$barrio.'">'.$barrio.'</option>';
            }
            ?>
            </select>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button> 
        </form>
```

Como Puedo hacer para que este select al cargar el formulario en modificar.php aparezca con el id Seleccionado. y al desplegar me muestre todos los demas en caso que quiera modificarlo.

Desde ya muchas gracias, si falta alguna informacion favor de avisarme.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mientras recorres el resultado de la consulta debes usar el atributo `selected` dentro de un condicional, y cuando pase por el mismo `id` entonces agregarlo. En caso contrario no.

De este modo:

```
if($id_barrio == $id) {
    $selected = ' selected ';
} else {
    $selected = '';
}
echo '<option value="'.$barrio.'" '.$selected.'>'.$barrio.'</option>';
```